# how to set object in middle of the screen in flash (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am new in flash developer. I want to **set my frame at the center of the screen interdependent of screen size**. but we are working on full screen view (means `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT`).

Logically I want one background image at back side, which cover all part of the screen, and on that background image I want to set my frame image at center of screen with fix size of (1000 X 750 px).

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

George Profenza is absolutely right, you need to set  StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE in as3 or add parameter in html like this

```
var so = new SWFObject("swf/sample.swf", "sample", "100%", "100%", "10");

so.addParam("scale", "noscale");
so.addParam("salign", "TOP_LEFT");
so.write("flashcontent");
```

note you also need to set slign property to TOP_LEFT.

one best tutorial i recommend for you [CLICK](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/web-design/build-a-fluid-website-layout/)